# How to set AngularJS drop down default value

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

my HTML code for drop down like follow:

```
 <select ng-model="selected_value" 
     ng-options="(x.version + ' ' + ' : ' + x.status) for x in allData"></select>
```

my Angular code like follow :
data comes from a rest service

```
$http.get(......).success(function (data, status){
   $scope.allData = data;
   $scope.selected_value = $scope.allData[0].version + " : " + $scope.allData[0].status;
});
```

Data comes to the drop down. but initially drop down does not display the value. It shows if only select the value. Can someone help on this issue.

Comment: Try `$scope.selected_value = $scope.allData[0]`. If you could make a http://plnkr.co/edit with some dummy data it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-selected="selected_value"` to the `select` element.

An example of what you are trying to achieve can be found in the [ngSelected documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it does not help me